# The plausibility of this atmosphere? and what the problems that it case?

Tags: atmosphere, habitability, ocean

The atmosphere have ~1 atm pressure at sea level, It does have water ocean maybe 10-30% of the surface, also it supports tectonic plates so the carbon cycle does work, and the Ocean is made mainly of H2O with traces of H2CO3 since it will absorb some CO2, The day is ~42 hours so will cause a lot of water to evaporate.

So based on that: I thought of this atmosphere:
89.5% N2
1-2% H2O
1-3% CO2
2-5% argon
(CO2 and Argon changeable choose any percentage for them)
0.5% other gases

Is it plausible with Earth-like temperature? if no how could a planet lose its CO2 and how could it support an H2O ocean with no problems, and will it be safe for the human skin? so u could walk there with just an Oxygen mask?

Comment: Where did the Carbon chemical compounds containing oxigen come from ? Outer space ? Or did the O2 all vanish into outer space, or was it used up, at some point ? What caused that..

Comment: @Goodies Do u mean CO2? by volcanoes, I know that carbon is very abounded in the universe, and Atomic Oxygen is extremely active, it will react with Hydrogen before it leaves the atmosphere, then it will react with Carbon, feel free to change the atmosphere. as long as the H2O or N2 are the dominant gases.

Comment: I asked because your proposed atmosphere contains about 1000x the amount of CO2 the earth atmosphere has. The atmosphere you propose resembles Earth's atmosphere of 2-3 billion years ago, before the Great Oxidation event, caused by photosynthesis  by early cyano lifeforms. When your planet is a very young planet with lots of vulcanism, asteroid impacts and without life, other conditions would probably inhibit walking around there with just a simple mask..

Comment: 5% H2O would be steamy. This corresponds to 100% humidity at about 33 C - approximately the conditions of a Turkish bath.

Comment: @Alexander I made the H2O changeable to 1-2%

Comment: @Goodies make that more like 20 times the primordial CO2.

Comment: There’s more that goes into plausibility. With a 42 hour day and low-ish amount of water, you might have the high-atmospheric water breakdown conditions, splitting water into hydrogen and oxygen that drift off into space, that is now believed to be responsible for drying Mars out. Or, maybe something is protecting the planet from that radiation? Or, you only care about short term stability (because we’re talking processes that will take much longer than a single human lifespan). Is there life reducing the atmosphere?

Comment: @JamesMcLellan It has a magnetic field, no life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it plausible? Yes.

Some concerns:

- If there is Cyanobacteria, it might be anaerobically converting your atmospheric CO2 to O2 over long time scales.
- Solar wind may be stripping the planets atmosphere and oceans over long time scales
- I wonder if you can keep the ocean from flipping to carbonic acid.
- You might possess some kind of cool carbonic acid cycle, where the ocean evaporates and some portion of the humidity is converted by solar radiation and the atmosphere to anhydrous carbonic acid. Then carbonic acid rain falls on the oceans which reduces it back to CO2 and water
- Keeping with the carbonic acid cycle thought : the carbonic acid, being denser, will sink below the water; leaving a pure water surface exposed for pickup by dry air. The deeper carbonic acid rain would decompose in the presence of water to CO2 and water, causing bubbles, or just a very high concentration of dissolved CO2

Comment: It's a double-planet system so it will have a strong magnetic-filed since both magnetic fields will merge, so I don't think SolarWinds will be able to strip the ocean, thanks for those Ideas.